# How to specify JAXB annotated classes when using Camel CXF rest endpoint?

Tags: jaxb, apache-camel, jax-rs, cxf

I have working Camel CXF endpoint, defined in a spring file like this:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="myEndpoint" address="myAddress"
  serviceClass="myServiceClass"
  loggingFeatureEnabled="true" skipFaultLogging="true" >
```

It works fine and can automatically pick up JAXB classes I have annotated with @XmlRootElement and @XmlSeeAlso. The same endpoint definition is used by two projects and I would like to move some of the classes to their appropriate sub-project, as really I need them to access other classes in that sub-project. The problem is that to do this, I have to remove them from the @XmlSeeAlso annotations for the top level classes. I've tried this and the JAXB context that is created when the endpoint is instantiated in the sub-project has no knowledge of the classes. What is the easiest way to resolve this? Initially I thought that it would be easy to find a property that allowed me to specify one or more additional classes to be given by CXF to the JAXB context, but the I can't see how to apply config given in the CXF docs to a Camel context. For example, config here:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html

Talks about using the "extraClass" property:

```
<bean id="jaxb" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider">
  <property name="extraClass">
     <list>
       <value>org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.resources.SuperBook</value>  
     </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

However I cannot see how to apply this when creating the route in Camel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <cxf:dataBinding>
            <bean id="extraJaxBClasses" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding">
                <property name="extraClass">
                    <list>
                        <value>your class here</value>
                        <value>your class here</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </cxf:dataBinding>
```

Comment: I got the similar situation and i got it working with this code - it works like a Charm.